# SQL Query CASE WHEN Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am doing a SQL Query to try to figure out production by shift... When I run this query.. it returns things that are in a location of 5-FG as having a shift 3... How is this even possible?

```
SELECT * FROM (select pt_desc1, pt_desc2, tr_part, tr_loc, tr_time, case when custpart = '' then         tr_part else custpart end as custpart, sum(tr_qty_loc) as 'Total', 
CASE WHEN tr_loc = '6-LDT2' then 'Dakkota'
    WHEN tr_loc = '5-FG' then 'Dexsys' end as 'location',
CASE WHEN tr_time > '14400' AND tr_time < '50400' AND tr_loc = '6-LDT2'Then '1'
    WHEN tr_time > '50400' AND tr_time < '75600' AND tr_loc = '6-LDT2' Then '2' 
    WHEN tr_time > '75600' OR tr_time < '14400' AND tr_loc = '6-LDT2' Then '3'
    WHEN tr_time > '21600' AND tr_time < '59400' AND tr_loc = '5-FG' Then '1'
    WHEN tr_time > '59400' or tr_time < '21600' AND tr_loc = '5-FG' Then '2' end as 'Shift'
from tr_hist_sql
join pt_mstr_sql on tr_part = pt_part
join cp_mstr_sql on pt_part = intpart
where tr_loc IN ('5-FG') 
and tr_type = 'rct-wo' 
group by tr_part, pt_desc1, pt_desc2, tr_loc, tr_time, case when custpart = '' then tr_part else      custpart end, CASE WHEN tr_time > '14400' AND tr_time < '50400' AND tr_loc = '6-LDT2' Then '1'
WHEN tr_time > '50400' AND tr_time < '75600' AND tr_loc = '6-LDT2' Then '2' 
WHEN tr_time > '75600' OR tr_time < '14400' AND tr_loc = '6-LDT2' Then '3'
WHEN tr_time > '21600' AND tr_time < '59400' AND tr_loc = '5-FG' Then '1'
    WHEN tr_time > '59400' or tr_time < '21600' AND tr_loc = '5-FG' Then '2'  end,
CASE WHEN tr_loc = '6-LDT2' then 'Dakkota'
    WHEN tr_loc = '5-FG' then 'Dexsys' end
having sum(tr_qty_loc) > 0) as dt
where Shift = 1 or shift = 2 or shift =3
```

order by tr_part

[image]

Comment: Please don't use screen shots to communicate code and data. They're harder to read, and we have to go through and re-type things to test a response. Copy/Pasting the code and data is much better.

Comment: `when tr_time > '75600' or tr_time < '14400'`  Your highlighted record clearly shows `tr_time` having a value of 77530 which is greater than 75600, so 3 is returned.

Comment: And it also shows that the tr_loc = '5-FG' meaning it should not be 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the line:

WHEN tr_time > '75600' or tr_time < '14400' and tr_loc = '6-LDT2' then '3'

**is being interpreted as:**

WHEN tr_time > '75600' or (tr_time < '14400' and tr_loc = '6-LDT2') then '3'

Then would come to the first clause:

WHEN tr_time > '75600'

Which **satisfies the OR statement, giving a value of '3' .**

Comment: It only looks at the first clause? What about the second AND in that line?

Comment: So basically put () around the entire thing?

Comment: My assumption is that it would see that the OR clause is satisfied immediately, and then skip the second half of it. That is simply how OR statements work. You only need one half of the statement to satisfy the condition, and if it is immediately satisfied, it doesn't need to continue with the second bit.

Comment: Changing the line to:    WHEN (tr_time > '75600' OR tr_time < '14400') AND tr_loc = '6-LDT2' Then '3' Worked!

Comment: It depends what you want. WHEN (tr_time > '75600' or tr_time < '14400') and tr_loc = '6-LDT2' then '3' from my assumption is what you are looking for